# How to initialise 1 Layer Neural Network Parameters?

Tags: neural-network, initialization

I am trying to initialize the following NN model:

[image]

```
def initialize_parameters(n_x, n_h, n_y):


W1 = np.random.randn(4,2) *0.01
b1 = np.zeros((4,1))
W2 = np.random.randn(1,4) * 0.01
b2 = np.zeros((1,1))


assert (W1.shape == (n_h, n_x))
assert (b1.shape == (n_h, 1))
assert (W2.shape == (n_y, n_h))
assert (b2.shape == (n_y, 1))

parameters = {"W1": W1,
              "b1": b1,
              "W2": W2,
              "b2": b2}

return parameters
```

My output comes out as:

```
W1 = [[-0.00416758 -0.00056267]
 [-0.02136196  0.01640271]
 [-0.01793436 -0.00841747]
 [ 0.00502881 -0.01245288]]
b1 = [[ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]]
W2 = [[-0.01057952 -0.00909008  0.00551454  0.02292208]]
b2 = [[ 0.]]
```

Whereas the correct answer should be:

```
W1  [[-0.00416758 -0.00056267] [-0.02136196 0.01640271] [-0.01793436 -0.00841747] [ 0.00502881 -0.01245288]]
b1  [[ 0.] [ 0.] [ 0.] [ 0.]]
W2  [[-0.01057952 -0.00909008 0.00551454 0.02292208]]
b2  [[ 0.]]
```

`W1`, and `b1` are obviously wrong, but I cannot make it work any other way. Newbie here.

Comment: The values look correct to me. Are you looking at the formatting difference in the output i.e between your expected result and the actual result?

Comment: Well I am doing Andrew NG new deep learning course and when I submit this answer, it doesn't get graded. I think w1 and b1 sizes are wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't accept because you hardcoded all values f.ex. 4 and 2 in np.random.randn(4,2) *0.01. Instead use the arguments n_h, n_x.